# Adding a Partner User to a Public Group

Tags: trigger, partner-communities

I'm trying to add Partner Users to a Public Group based on a checkbox. It works fine for Users but I can't seem to find how to correctly reference the Partner User in my trigger. As sample is below:

```
trigger AddToPG on Contact (after insert, after update) {
    List<GroupMember> GMlist = new List<GroupMember>();
    Set<String> contactEmails = new Set<String>();

    for(Contact con : Trigger.New) {
        //create a set with the contact email addresses
        contactEmails.add(con.email);
    }

    //query for the related users and put them in a map,
    //where the key is the email and the value is the user
    Map<String, User> emailUserMap = new Map<String, User> ();

    for(User aUser : [select id, email from User where email in : contactEmails]){
        emailUserMap.put(aUser.email, aUser);
    }

    system.debug(emailUserMap);

    List<Id> userIdList = new List<Id>();

    for(Contact con : Trigger.New) {
        if(con.Flow_Concrete__c == TRUE) {    
            userIdList.add(emailUserMap.get(con.email).id);
        }
    }  

    //dymanically get the get group id.
    Group theGroup = [select id from Group where Name = 'Concrete'];

    if(null != theGroup){
        //call the contact trigger helper if the group exists. 
        //This method adds the user to the group
        ContactTriggerHelper.addUsersToGroup(theGroup.id,userIdList );
    }
}
```

Comment: The user object contains a reference to the contact for partner users. Is there a reason you're not using that field instead of the email?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this will actually fix your issue, but I modified your code to be a bit cleaner:

```
trigger AddToPG on Contact (after insert, after update) {
    // List<GroupMember> GMlist = new List<GroupMember>(); // You're code doesn't seem to actually use this variable?
    Set<Id> usersToAdd = new Set<Id>();
    Id partnerProfileId = [
        SELECT Id
        FROM Profile
        WHERE Name = 'Partner Profile Name'
    ].Id;

    // Find your partner users based on the contactId instead of email
    // More reliable
    List<User> partnerUsers = new List<User>([
        SELECT Id, ContactId
        FROM User
        WHERE ContactId IN :Trigger.New
            AND ProfileId = partnerProfileId
    ]);

    // Loop through users you find, not the contacts in the trigger
    // This loop will run at most once per contact, but often far fewer times
    // Where as looping through contacts guarantees the worst case scenario, every time
    for (User u : partnerUsers) {
        if (Trigger.newMap.get(u.contactId).Flow_Concrete__c == TRUE) {    
            usersToAdd.add(u.Id);
        }
    }  

    // I would consider finding a way to get rid of this query
    // Hardcoding the Id is far from ideal but in sfdc limits are king
    // Alternatively you can use custom meta-data or custom settings
    Group theGroup = [
        SELECT Id 
        FROM Group 
        WHERE Name = 'Concrete'
    ];

    if (theGroup != null) {
        ContactTriggerHelper.addUsersToGroup(theGroup.id, usersToAdd);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I should mention that I have 6 different check boxes that the code has to loop through as each contact/user can have a different combo of selections and there's a helper class that uses the List<GroupMember>. I'll see if I can modify it correctly to cover the remaining checkboxes.